# The installation of RTL8188EUS Wifi adapter interupts and displays two errors

Tags: networking, pi-4

Apparently as the Raspberry pi 4 model b does not support Monitor mode, i plan on using a WiFi adaptor to carry out the task.But when i try to install the drivers of the adaptor, there seems to be an erroras shown below.Any suggestion on how i can fix it.

```
##################################################
    Realtek Wi-Fi driver Auto installation script
    Novembor, 21 2011 v1.1.0
    ##################################################
    Decompress the driver source tar ball:
        rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222.tar.gz
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/runwpa
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_xmit.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_ioctl_query.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_bt_mp.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/efuse/
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/core/rtw_recv.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/usb_ops_linux.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8723a_xmit.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/sdio_osintf.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/Hal8723PwrSeq.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8188e_sreset.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_p2p.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/pci_hal.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/drv_conf.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/usb_vendor_req.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/linux/
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/linux/wireless.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/osdep_service.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8188e_hal.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8188e_led.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/gspi_osintf.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_ioctl_query.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_eeprom.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/drv_types_xp.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtl8723a_cmd.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/include/rtw_byteorder.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalHWImg8188E_MAC.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/Hal8188EFWImg_CE.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalHWImg8188E_MAC.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalHWImg8188E_BB.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/Hal8188EFWImg_CE.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalHWImg8188E_FW.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/odm_RegConfig8188E.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/Hal8188ERateAdaptive.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e/HalPhyRf_8188e.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_HWConfig.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_debug.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_interface.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_interface.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_HWConfig.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_reg.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_RegDefine11AC.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/OUTSRC/odm_debug.h
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/hal_intf.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_sreset.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_rxdesc.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_cmd.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_rf6052.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/Hal8188EPwrSeq.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_mp.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_phycfg.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_dm.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/usb/
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/usb/usb_halinit.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/usb/rtl8188eu_led.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/usb/rtl8188eu_recv.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/usb/rtl8188eu_xmit.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/usb/usb_ops_linux.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_hal_init.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/rtl8188e/rtl8188e_xmit.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/hal_com.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/hal/HalPwrSeqCmd.c
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/clean
    rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222
    Authentication requested [root] for make clean:
    rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
    rm -fr .tmp_versions
    rm -fr Module.symvers ; rm -fr Module.markers ; rm -fr modules.order
    cd core/efuse ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
    cd core ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
    cd hal/rtl8188e/usb ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
    cd hal/rtl8188e ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
    cd hal/OUTSRC/rtl8188e ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
    cd hal/OUTSRC/ ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
    cd hal ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
    cd os_dep/linux ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
    cd os_dep ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
    Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
    make ARCH=armv7l CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.10.11-v7l+/build M=/home/pi/Documents/Network adapter/linux/RTL8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222/driver/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.1.4_6773.20130222  modules
    make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.11-v7l+'
    Makefile:681: arch/armv7l/Makefile: No such file or directory
    make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/armv7l/Makefile'.  Stop.
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.11-v7l+'
    make: *** [Makefile:678: modules] Error 2
    ##################################################
    Compile make driver error: 2
    Please check error Mesg
    ##################################################
```

Comment: Have a look at the drivers on http://downloads.fars-robotics.net they have been built for the Pi under Buster / Stretch (not tried Jessie)

Answer (score 2):

At the prices nowadays for an USB/WiFi dongle below 10 € I would say it isn't worth the effort to fiddle with a third party driver installation. It isn't only to install the driver once, you have to monitor it with every automatic kernel and firmware update from the repository. Instead, I would use one of the many compatible dongles that are directly supported by the kernel, and will work out of the box. You can look at [RPi USB Wi-Fi Adapters](https://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters) to learn what dongles are usable. The only problem is to find which of them [support the monitor mode.](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=wifi+dongles+that+support+monitor+mode&ia=web)